# C Sockets termination

Tags: c, sockets

1. If a read() on a tcp/ip socket receives end of file, will the presence of eof causes the socket to terminate?
2. When performing read() on a tcp/ip socket, if the size of stream is unknown, would a reader receive an EOF, so that he can stop reading further?

Answer (score 2):

No to both. There is no such thing as an EOF in the TCP protocol.

If you want to define one in your application protocol, you can do so (and you should), but `read` won't stop or close the socket when it sees it.

TCP is purely stream base. Extracting "packets" of data is up to the application.

If you only need to send one message over the TCP connetion, you can close the socket on the sender side when you're done sending. Then the `read` receiving side will only read as much as what was sent, and return `0` when no more is left to read. But you'll have to re-open a new connection to send the next message in that case.

Comment: I agree - needs the FIN message for the TCP socket to start the close down.

Comment: TCP Is a stream based protocol and Stream by definition has a stream head and a stream end. so if a sender sends data, the stream on receiver side should have a stream head and a stream end. The stream end i am asumming is EOF. Is that not correct?

Comment: @Jimm - no it is not correct.  There is no head or end at the application level.  TCP is sending and handling packets at the lower level.  It takes care of setting up the stream and ending it.  At the app level you basically just know there is nothing left to read when zero bytes are returned from a read.

Comment: I thought read() returns -1 to indicate EOF? is that not correct ?

Comment: Read the man page. "If successful, the number of bytes actually read is returned.  Upon reading end-of-file, zero is returned." `-1` is returned only when an error occurs.

Comment: Ok, so if read() returns 0, can it be assumed that if sender sent 1gb, the receiver has received 1gb? I am just interested in knowing that the data sender has sent, is fully received by the receiver in the case receiver does not know the data size before hand. OR can read() return 0, if due to latecny, only 5 bytes are read out of 1gb and read() is waiting for rest of bytes to arrive ?

Comment: If read returns 0 on a socket, the other side has closed at least it's write side of the socket, and that there were no errors (i.e. all sent packets have arrived).